# Gen2 and best practices for cached items in ASP.NET site

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a high traffic site that needs to see results of a game every 10 minutes.  These games are stored in cache and filtered through there for various means.  There could be 200+ events going on during the weekend.

I noticed some high GC going on which causes a site delay.  After some investigation I noticed my Gen2 is three times larger than Gen0 and nothing in Gen1.

This led me to believe that my cached objects eventually go to Gen2, and stay there even when expired. Then high garbage collection occurs on those Gen2 objects. Is there a better approach than what I am doing in the code below and could this be the issue with my high GC?

[image]

```
  public static T GetInitializedCache<T>(string key, Func<CacheData<T>> getData, int minutes, bool skip = false) 
    {
        if (!skip)
        {
            key = key.ToLower();

            var value = HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
            if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(T))
            {
                CacheData<T> data = getData();
                if (data != null && data.Data != null && Config.Debugging.EnableCaching)
                {
                    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, data.Data, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(data.Minutes ?? minutes), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
                }
                return data != null ? data.Data : default(T);
            }
            return (T)value;
        }
        else
        {
            var data = getData();
            return data != null ? data.Data : default(T);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a 32-bit app? From the screenshot I see it is LeanSentry so IIS hosted ASP.NET (not Core) app, right? It would be great to observe the GC behaviour with the help of PerfView and its GC Stats report.

Comment: It's an ASP.NET MVC 5 and .NET 4.8 website, not core.

Comment: Great. Without more data it is impossible to guess what's the reason.

Comment: GameComplex takes up most of the space with String first.  GameComplex is stored in cash as you can tell from the bottom graph.  I am asking are things store in cache sent to Gen2. That should be obvious to know for someone right?

Comment: Well, long living things like cached objects are likely to be eventually promoted to Gen2, yes. But does knowing that helps in any way in solving your concern? Not sure. I suggested much better way of analyzing what's happening with the help of PerfView.

Comment: Ill use Perfview but I used LeanSentry already and know what objects are in my Gen2 space.  My guess is Gen2 gets so large that eventually it GC and takes forever, and these are mainly my cached objects that expired and are being collected.

Comment: Perfview showing no Gen2 items, odd.  I think I need more Ram.

Comment: If it is 32-bit process, RAM will not help as you may hit the limits. If it is not, more RAM may be even more harmful - Gen2 GC will be triggered even later (so it will be even slower). What are you seeing is Gen2 GC triggered less often than cache items expiring - so even expired, they just sit there waiting for the GC. This is because cache is kind of against generational hyphoteses upon which GCs are built. Going off-the heap (Redis?) or make GC more aggresive (Concurrent Workstation? GCHeapCount? GCHeapHardLimit?).

Comment: I was thinking about Redis, however that is not a good idea during our peek season.  This is a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? 

I have a very similar problem. I think about using redis, but I'm kinda concerned about overhead that redis brings (http request for each cache access?)

Comment: I did not, only cut down on the size and timeout of my cache.